# Add colon to string at a certain position

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a website where I am calculating the hours and minutes between two times (Starttime Endtime) which has been entered inside two input elements. The result is saved inside a label.

Here is an example:

```
Starttime: 08:00
Endtime: 15:30
TimeSpend: 7 hours 30 Minutes
```

I need to send the value Timespend back to my backend but not in this form. I want to send it in a form like:

```
7:30
```

etc.

I filter the hours and minutes out with this JavaScript: `replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');` The result is 730.

How can I add a colon between 7 and 30 to let look
like: `730 --> 7:30`? The Same should work for `1120 --> 11:20`.

Comment: why not change the calculation to the wanted format, instead of changing later to the new format?

Comment: because i have to display it like so

Comment: When you display the values, save the original values you used instead of  trying to pull them later from the display. This is a prime example why you should separate your data and presentation.

Comment: i mean separate calculation from display format. then you can use a different format for another purpose.

Comment: i guess that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a second regular expression to `timespend`, which identifies the last two characters and inserts a colon in front:

```
replace(/(.{2})$/,':$1');
```

**Working example:**

```js
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

var timespend = '7 hours 30 Minutes';

paragraphs[0].textContent = timespend;

timespend = timespend.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

paragraphs[1].textContent = timespend;

timespend = timespend.replace(/(.{2})$/,':$1');

paragraphs[2].textContent = timespend;
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your

> TimeSpend: 7 hours 30 Minutes

using strtotime() and date() like:

```
$time = "7 hours 30 Minutes";
echo date('H:i', strtotime($time));
```

Output : 09:42

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope it helps. see the `jsfiddle.net/4y6f1t25/`and check

Answer (score 0):

var timeInHourMinutes = "7 hours 30 minutes";

var res = timeInHourMinutes.replace("hours ", ":");

res = res .replace("minutes", " ");

console.log(res);